# Read input in pattern match branch

Tags: input, console, pattern-matching, rust

My program should read some parameters from the command line. If someone does not provide an optional password parameter the program should ask for it. Therefore the corresponding field is modeled as an `Option` type.

This works well if the parameter is provided from the command line ( option having the value of `Some("...")`, but the branch matching the `None` case does not ask for input.

The simplified program looks like

```
fn main() {
    use std::io::{self,Read};

    let arg : Option<String> = None; // Does not terminate
    //let arg : Option<String> = Some("Some arg".to_string()); // works well printing 'Some arg'
    println!("Checking for password");


    let password = match arg {
        Some(val) => val.to_string(),
        None => {
            print!("Password:");
         let mut buffer = String::new();
         io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
         buffer
        }
    };

    println!("password is {}", password);
}
```

Running the program preinitialized with `Some("Some arg")` prints the string "password is Some arg" to the console as expected, but switching to the None does nothing, even not terminating the program.

Could you spot my mistake or give me some advice? I am using rustc verison `rustc 1.4.0 (8ab8581f6 2015-10-27)`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `read_line()`:

```
fn main() {
    use std::io::{self,Read};

    let arg : Option<String> = None; // Does not terminate
    //let arg : Option<String> = Some("Some arg".to_string()); // works well printing 'Some arg'
    println!("Checking for password");

    let password = match arg {
        Some(val) => val.to_string(),
        None => {
            print!("Password:");
            let mut buffer = String::new();
            io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
            buffer
        }
    };

    println!("password is {}", password);
}
```

The `read_to_string()` function reads until end of file.
Your program does indeed read input, but you need to send it the `EOF` character (`Ctrl-D` on Linux) for it to continue executing.

Comment: Thank you, that was one problem. The other one is that I have to flush the output stream in order to get some prompt on the console. So I need to add ``io::stdout::flush()`` after the print as well.